# Third-party SSO launch from Gmail sends 502 error

Tags: single-sign-on, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

All SSO redirections to third-party apps from Google Mail is giving the below 502 error. Accessing https://apis.google.com/ is also sending a 404 error.

Any idea on what causes this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We spent a day and a half troubleshooting this. After looking at our firewall, ISP, and Google, Google finally admitted to an error on their end. Here's their response:

Hello Nathan,

Thank you for contacting Google Cloud support. I understand that you have been experiencing some issues with the usage of the G Suite App Launcher to select and use Marketplace apps listed in this feature.

Few minutes ago I tried to contact you to the number +1 XXX-XXX-XXXX, but unfortunately I was unable to reach you. My name is Oscar and I’m part of the G suite API support team. If you would like to be contacted within a specific time frame, feel free to share with me the best time, date and phone number to reach you.

As confirmed during a brief voice message today, the behavior noticed is now considered an active know issue which our product engineering team continues to work on, so this could be resolved soon. In order to continue using any of the Marketplace apps you have listed within the App Launcher, you can still be able to use each app direct URL as which is not affected.

This case will continue to be monitored by our internal team and our support team, in order to share any relevant information as soon as it is available about a possible ETA for the resolution of this issue.

I would like to add that there is another case you've created which number is ######## reporting the same issue. This case is now considered as a duplicate case, however will continue to be open during the time this case is also open. You'll receive a notification confirming the status of that same case within few minutes.

If you’d like to speak over the phone, let me know by replying to this email with the best time to call and I’ll reach you. Just to let you know, I’ll be out of the office during the weekend, but we have 24/7 support. So if you need immediate assistance you can always reach us via phone following these steps https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?&ref_topic=7067151 or I can arrange for someone else to take over your case if necessary.

Best regards,

Oscar
Google Cloud Support

Comment: Thanks for the reports. The issue should be fixed now, if that's not the case please let me know.